# Find "word" index in paragraph with jQuery (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex, word-boundary

I have a string that represents a paragraph of text.

```
var paragraph = "It is important that the word cold is not partially selected where we search for the word old";
```

I want to be able to search this paragraph for the index of a "word" and have it do an exact match on a "word".  For example, when searching for "old".  I should only get 1 result, not 2 since matching the "old" in "cold" is invalid.

Comment: You can use the regex `/\bold\b/` to match occurrences of `old` surrounded by word boundaries. What exactly do you want to do with these matches though? Count? Replace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the word-boundary search `\b`:

```
var idx = paragraph.search(/\bold\b/i);
```

This matches things like white space, dashes etc. that separate words.

Comment: `match` returns any matches, not the index of the match.